# Using return $q.when in Hot Towel Angular datacontext

Tags: json, http, angularjs, hottowel, q

I've created a web application using the Hot Towel Angular template, and I want to add a service function to the 'datacontext'.

Code is:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'datacontext';
    angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', '$http', datacontext]);

    function datacontext(common, $http) {
        var $q = common.$q;

        var service = {
            getFunctions: getFunctions
        };

        return service;

        function getFunctions() {
            var f = [];
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/users/google/repos',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                f = data;
                console.log('f=*' + f + '*');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('error!');
            });

            return $q.when(f);
        }
    }
})();
```

I see that the console shows some objects:

```
f=*[object Object],[object Object],[object O...
```

But when using this in my functionController.js file :

```
function getFunctions() {
  return datacontext.getFunctions().then(function (data) {
    console.log('data=*' + data + '*');
    return vm.functions = data;
  });
}
```

The value for data  is set to **undefined**.

I'm missing something, please help identify the error.

Comment: Your `$q.when(f)` simply wraps the empty array `[]`, which is the current value of `f` when the return is executed, into a promise.  This promise is then resolved immediately with this value, i.e., your then-callback is called with data=[].

Comment: Ok I see, but what's the solution to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

The getFunctions function in the **datacontext** should return the $http promise object, like this:

```
function getFunctions() {
  return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/google/repos')
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert('error ! : ' + status);
  });
}
```

And in the **controller**, you can use the returned json object as follows:

```
function getRepos() {
  return datacontext.getRepos().then(function (httpResult) {
    vm.repos = httpResult.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this really the right answer? To me returning the $http promise completely defeats the purpose of using data contexts as it exposes the data access implementation details to the consumer. The consumer will be dependent of the data access implementation, so you won't be able use a caching strategy or a fake without changing the consumer. In my opinion the original idea was good, just badly implemented.